# How to compare values from response of two different requests in SOAP UI using groovy?

Tags: api, groovy, automated-tests, soapui, web-api-testing

I am using SOAP UI Pro for test automation and I am new for that. I am using this tool for Rest API automation.
I sent a POST service request and got some response for example : unique id, first name, last name.

Now I send another GET request with input parameters as first name, last name from my previous POST request response (using property transfer step) and in response I got another unique id (response of GET).

My requirement is to compare these two unique ids from these two different responses using groovy and mark test pass or fail based on the outcome. Please help.

Comment: Are you using soap / rest (xml or json) api?

Comment: I am using rest (json) api

Comment: Why do you need to use Groovy? Such assertion is handled natively in SoapUI.

Comment: May be because, verification to be done after fetching the required values from different steps.

Comment: @Rao- Not exactly, this can be accomplished with assertions.The reason was because I don't see any assertion that can pass the test if there is a mismatch for two different ids. And I needed to pass the test at mismatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the properties you want to compare and perform and `assert` checking your required condition in *groovy script*.

You comment in your question that you're using a *Property transfer step* however you didn't tell where you're storing your results due I suppose for example that you're storing the values in *TestCase* properties:

```
// you've to use the name of the property you set in the property transfer step
def fn = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue('firstName_firstResponse')
def fn2 = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue('firstName_secondResponse')
assert fn == fn2, "THE FIRST NAME AREN'T EQUALS"
```

In the *groovy script testStep* context you've a `testRunner` object which you can use to access `testCase`, `testSuite`... and then get the desired property.

Another possible approach is to do the same but getting the properties directly from the `response` of your *testStep* and performing *XPath*, to do so you can use the follow *groovy script*:

```
def fn = context.expand('${TestStepName_1#response#*://firstName}')
def fn2 = context.expand('${TestStepName_2#response#*://firstName}')
assert fn == fn2, "THE FIRST NAME AREN'T EQUALS"
```

Like `testRunner` the `context` object is already on the context of *groovy testStep*. The notation used in `context.expand` is `${Test Step Name#response#XPath}`.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks albciff, awesome bro! 
You saved me. And yes I was saving the previous values in the test case property file. 

Thanks once again. I don't know why my question is given '-1'.

Comment: @Python_Novice nice to help you. I don't make the down vote but probably is due to the missing details (I'm just guessing), try updating your answer with its, maybe then the downvoter comes again an undo the action... if not at least in the futur maybe other user finds your question helpful and upvote it `:)`